# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client while parsing data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-csv-parse

I am using csv parser to read csv file and passing received data of csv file to ejs template file to print so the data is in object format, so I have used stringyfy but getting error due to this.

Error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client:
```

Node js code

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    fs.createReadStream('./Employee.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', function (rows) {
            try {
            var ParsedData=  data:JSON.stringify(rows);
                 res.render('Emp_details',{data:ParsedData});
            }
            catch (err) {
                //error handler
            }
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            //some final operation
        });


});
```

Code to print data in ejs template file:

```
<% for(var i = 1; i<= data1.length; i++) { %>
         <%=i %>
       <% } %>
```

Comment: [no solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+set+headers+after+they+are+sent+to+the+client%5Bnode.js%5D)?

Comment: @jps I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean, did you search on SO to find a solution? And did you not find anything helpful among the more than 100 other Q/As (linked in my comment) which ask about the same error?

Comment: @jps I tried other solutions provided on stackoverflow but didn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `res.render` can only be called once but you are calling it **every time** the `data` event fires.

You need to call it where you put the comment `//some final operation` after collecting all the data.

Comment: I found your comment useful can you please explain more about this. I have no idea of this concept.

Comment: can you please explain after your suggestion I kept  render in final stage.but render is not working here

Comment: Did you collect all the data in the `data` events so it is available to the render function?

Comment: I am simply using stream function to get all values and passing to ejs page.